# Function get_day_link() give 404 error when there's no news in the day

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

My website is powered by wordpress, at the homepage has a buttom that redirect the visitors to the dayly news, but when there's no news in the day my website give a not found error page, i does want do display this buttom only when have news in the day, someone know how to fix that, check my code bellow:

```
<?php if (of_get_option('pm_date') ) { //Get current date if enabled ?>
    <div class="date">
        <a href="<?php echo get_day_link('', '', ''); ?>" rel="tooltip" data-original-title="<?php _e('Veja as Notícias de Hoje!','')?>" data-placement="left"><?php echo date_i18n('j F Y', time()); ?></a>
            <span class="corner custom-color"></span>    
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

arguments are missing in the get_day_link function,

you may try like this:

```
<?php 
$archive_year  = get_the_time('Y'); 
$archive_month = get_the_time('m'); 
$archive_day   = get_the_time('d'); 
?>
<a href="<?php echo get_day_link( $archive_year, $archive_month, $archive_day); ?>">This day's posts</a>
?>
```

to get a post on today